# Export a concrete value from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I want to export a concrete value of a field on mongodb. The output of my mongoexport is like this:

```
{"_id":"00:XX:XX:2a:15:e08503904736321657210145581","timestamp":1496095264,"MAC":"00:XX:XX:2a:15:XX","RSSI":24,"manufacturer":"30:XX:X"}

{"_id":"00:XX:XX:2b:10:b08503818454462501125707070","timestamp":1496181546,"MAC":"00:XX:XX:2b:10:XX","RSSI":29,"manufacturer":"b0:XX:XX"}
```

And this with 5M values. Is it possible to export only the value of one "MAC". This is my commando to export the values:

```
mongoexport -u usser -p pwd --host host:port -d pingsDB -c 2017-05-25 --authenticationDatabase admin -f "timestamp,MAC,RSSI,manufacturer"  -o mongo.csv
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a query filter, like so.

`mongoexport -u usser -p pwd --host host:port -d pingsDB -c 2017-05-25 --authenticationDatabase admin -f "timestamp,MAC,RSSI,manufacturer"  --query { "MAC":"00:XX:XX:2b:10:XX"} -o mongo.csv`

See the full docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Answer (score 0):

Answering to @JonLuca, it worked making a fix on the syntax:

```
mongoexport -u usser -p pwd --host host:port -d pingsDB -c 2017-05-25 
--authenticationDatabase admin -f "timestamp,MAC,RSSI,manufacturer"  
--query { "MAC":"00:XX:XX:2b:10:XX"} -o mongo.csv
```

to

```
  mongoexport -u usser -p pwd --host host:port -d pingsDB -c 2017-05-25 
  --authenticationDatabase admin -f "timestamp,MAC,RSSI,manufacturer"  
  --query '{ "MAC":"00:XX:XX:2b:10:XX"}' -o mongo.csv
```

Take a look on the `' '` before and after the `{ }`

Thank you!!